# How to make checkout and delete the tags in svn

Tags: svn

I tried to add a tag to the project and I tried it as follows.
As I am beginner to SVN i tries it as follows.

In my terminal I used this command for setting a tag to the project.

```
Sekhars-Mac-book:desktop adminbluepal$ svn copy Parkable \
>  http://svn.parkable.com/repos/Parkable/tags/release-1.0 \
>  -m "Tagging the 1.0 release of the 'Parkable' project."
```

The response I got from this command is:

```
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://svn.parkable.com/repos/Parkable/tags': 200 OK     (http://svn.parkable.com)
```

Can anyone help be how to checkout the tag I set, and how to delete the tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the response, it appears that the tag command has not worked.  If it had, you should have got the following message.

```
Committed revision nnn.
```

So you may not have to worry about deleting it.

It is likely that the url specified for the tagging is incorrect.

Comment: Ohh Thanq raghuram.Hey u please suggest me the steps how to make checkout of a tag?

Comment: svn co url-of-the-tag - e.g. svn co http://svn.parkable.com/repos/Parkable/tags/my-tag

Comment: Actually I am confusing how to use the host name.from where we can get that Url.